Can't get open data with Woocommerce REST API
Trying to fetch categories, products and even orders by customer role user for which i generated keys and gave read/write access.
always get
{"code":"woocommerce_rest_cannot_view","message":"Sorry, you cannot list resources.","data":{"status":403}}%    

cant find any direct explanation on the issue woocommerce doc says that customer:

Have read access only for most capacities. This is the equivalent status to a normal blog subscriber.
Can edit their own account information.
View past/present orders.

so why it not possible to get even orders, and what the reason to forbid getting open data or making order
ps im using v3 api version
